# During 'mount', parcel threw an error: single-spa minified message #2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, micro-frontend, single-spa

I am trying to call a microfrontend inside a modal. I am using single-spa to call microfrontends inside my angular app container.
This is the code :

- function call from app container to open a modal

  html:
  `<button beys-fab-button [icon]="'diagonal-arrow-right-up'" (click)="opentTemplateModal()"></button>`

  ts :
   `opentTemplateModal() { this.modal = this.modalService.openExtraLarge( "Template", EditingTestComponent ); }`
- EditingTestComponent (component inside it I want to call my microfrontend)

  html :
  `<div class="row class"> <parcel [config]="app" [mountParcel]="mountParcel" > </parcel></div>`

  ts :

```
import { Component, NgZone, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { mountRootParcel } from "single-spa";

@Component({
  selector: "app-editing-test",
  templateUrl: "./editing-test.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./editing-test.component.css"],
})
export class EditingTestComponent implements OnInit {
  mountParcel = mountRootParcel;

  app;
  constructor() {}
  subscribeToVerification: any;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.app = System.import("editique");
  }
}
```

And the System.import works fine so there is no importing problem, I am running locally an angular app and import its main.js and nalme it "editique" .
It seems like there is a mounting problem : `During 'mount', parcel threw an error: single-spa minified message #2`